# pyvisa succeeds with "*IDN?" but fails with VI_ERROR_TMO: Timeout expired before operation completed with all other commands

Tags: python, linux, visa, pyvisa

My instrument responds properly to "*IDN?" with `Rigol Technologies,DG822,DG8A233304081,00.02.06.00.01`.

When I try to issue any other commands, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/918AutoRelock/rigol_f_gen.py", line 16, in <module>
    rigol.query(OUTPUT1_ON)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 648, in query
    return self.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 486, in read
    message = self._read_raw().decode(enco)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.py", line 442, in _read_raw
    chunk, status = self.visalib.read(self.session, size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyvisa_py/highlevel.py", line 519, in read
    return data, self.handle_return_value(session, status_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyvisa/highlevel.py", line 251, in handle_return_value
    raise errors.VisaIOError(rv)
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

The instrument responds to the command. If I tell it to turn on the output, it will! The program just crashes likely because it doesn't receive the correct acknowledgement back from the device.

Additionally, once I issue a command, I cannot control the device physically with the buttons or knobs until I reboot it. Any fix for this?

```
import pyvisa

RIGOL_ID = 'USB0::6833::1603::DG8A233304081::0::INSTR'
ID_QUERY = "*IDN?"
OUTPUT1_ON = ":OUTP1 ON"
SINE = ":SOUR1:APPL:SIN 500,2.5,1,90"

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
try:
    rigol = rm.open_resource(RIGOL_ID)
    response = rigol.query("*IDN?")
    print(response)
except (ValueError):
    print("The device was not found. Make sure you run the program with sudo privileges.")
# rigol.query(SINE)
rigol.query(OUTPUT1_ON)

exit()
```

How can I fix this problem? I tried looking in the programming guide, but I couldn't find any reference. I'm copy and pasting the example queries directly from the PDF.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you expect an actual answer from the device, therefore want to [`query`](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/resources.html#pyvisa.resources.SerialInstrument.query) data from it, which is a combination of writing and reading?

Most likely the devices does not return any information back to you, therefore [writing](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/resources.html#pyvisa.resources.MessageBasedResource.write) the commands to the device without waiting for an answer would be the correct way.

Example:

```py
rigol.write(':OUTP1 ON')
```

Usually only data queries, indicated by a trailing `?`, e.g. `*IDN?` in your example return a result.